# Sorting Database images by date

Tags: php, database, image

I have a basic upload and gallery view for photos. However, the view for the gallery is by oldest first.

Can someone show me an easy way for me to sort this by newest first? This is my PHP which shows the images:

```php
<?php
   $sql="SELECT * FROM chiseldonuploads";
   $result_set=mysql_query($sql);

   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set));
   {
?>
       <img class="photos" src="uploads/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>"></td>
<?php
   }
?>
```

Comment: is there any column in the table `chiseldonuploads` to store the time of image upload?

Comment: You will need to add the date data type to your table then do a descending sort when querying the data

Comment: Like @jeff said, you can sort out by the date data type column or use this query. 'SELECT * FROM chiseldonuploads order by id desc'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case your table *chiseldonuploads* has column date, for example *created_date* you can order it by date, or if it does not have date, you can try ordering by *id* of the table:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM chiseldonuploads ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Here *id* has to be replaced with column name representing id column in your table. But if you have date column, you have to order by date.